# Rsync copy symlinks and exclude subfolder

Tags: bash, rsync, symbolic-link

I'm trying to use rsync to copy a directory recursively, and copying symlinks referent. I also want to exclude certain directories that are located within the symlink. This is the part that's not working.

I'm using the following command:

```
rsync -aPL source/ dest/ --exclude source/dir/symlink/node_modules
```

Directory structure:

```
.
|-dir
|---symlink
|-----another_dir
|-----node_modules
```

Unfortunately, it is still copying the node_modules directory, even though I'm trying to exclude it. Any idea how to do this, if possible?

Answer (score 0):

I just realised I don't have to specify the full directory in the exclude, and if I just exclude the node_modules directory by it's name, it works perfectly:

```
 rsync -aPL source/ dest/ --exclude node_modules
```